# how can I get a audio data from webm file using libwebm parser

Tags: parsing, webm

I have a webm file which include audio data(using opus codec).
I want to use libwebm parser, but I cant find infor about that, and I dont know how to do.
there is a few sample code.

anyway I succeed to parse(just do by the sample code)
but that is just only print, parsing is ok.
I want ther really audio data, but dont know how can I get it.

below linke is demo code which i used.
https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm/blob/master/webm_parser/demo/demo.cc

and below is the results.
how can I get the audio data??

EBML                                 header: [0, 5)  body: [5, 36)

EBMLVersion: 1
  EBMLReadVersion: 1
  EBMLMaxIDLength: 4
  EBMLMaxSizeLength: 8
  DocType: webm
  DocTypeVersion: 4
  DocTypeReadVersion: 2

Segment                              header: [36, 48)  body: [48, ?)

Info                               header: [48, 53)  body: [53, 78)

```
TimecodeScale: 1000000
MuxingApp: Chrome
WritingApp: Chrome
```

Tracks                             header: [78, 83)  body: [83, 146)

```
TrackEntry                       header: [83, 85)  body: [85, 146)

  TrackNumber: 1
  TrackUID: 15362115268361576
  TrackType: 2 (audio)
  FlagEnabled (implicit): 1
  FlagDefault (implicit): 1
  FlagForced (implicit): 0
  FlagLacing (implicit): 1
  CodecID: A_OPUS
  CodecPrivate: <19 bytes>
  SeekPreRoll (implicit): 0
  Audio
    SamplingFrequency: 48000
    Channels: 1
    BitDepth: 32
```

Cluster                            header: [146, 158)  body: [158, ?)
    Timecode: 0

```
SimpleBlock                      header: [161, 164)  body: [164, 1419)
  track number: 1
  frames: 1
  timecode: 0
  lacing: 0 (none)
  flags: visible, key frame
  frame byte range: [168, 1419)

SimpleBlock                      header: [1419, 1422)  body: [1422, 2427)
  track number: 1
  frames: 1
  timecode: 59
  lacing: 0 (none)
  flags: visible, key frame
  frame byte range: [1426, 2427)

SimpleBlock                      header: [2427, 2430)  body: [2430, 3396)
```

Comment: I'm interested. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Hi, I didnt figure out. 
but I found some code using libwebm parser.
below is the git code.
using this, I can parse to raw audio data from webm file

https://github.com/zaps166/libsimplewebm

Comment: Thanks! I also came across [nestegg](https://github.com/kinetiknz/nestegg) and the newer [webm_parser](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm/tree/master/webm_parser)